# Linux kernel static_key_false always false

Tags: linux-kernel

I have this condition: `if static_key_false(&key))` and its always false! Doesnt matter where I increment (`static_key_slow_inc`) the key!

The documentations claims that even in run time a change should be picked up and the kernel patched accordingly.

It only happens with the jump label implementation of `static_key_false`, the other one (with the unlikely) works fine.

Comment: Is [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49616679/change-static-branch-after-its-been-set-in-linux-kernel) describes the same problem? If so, it is better to improve (edit) the previous question, than ask a new one.

Comment: Not quite... Thats why I asked a new one, I'll close the previous one since its no longer relevant

Comment: @tomer.z: You did not have to remove that previous question completely. Simply adding a comment that it was no longer relevant would have been enough. Other users could still benefit from it.